# How to write an HTML document using external JavaScript from another webpage

Tags: javascript

I want to write an html document using external JavaScript from another webpage.

Is it possible to permanently change an html web page using JavaScript.

Comment: sometimes yes, sometimes no..

Comment: Please give a more **detailed** question.

Comment: If you're asking "is it possible?", the answer would be yes.  If you want help with something, please, let us know.

Comment: you can update the page with AJAX requests to simulate permanent changes, but behind the hood you will need server script to do the "changing"

Comment: I find this hard to understand: _"can change permenantly change in html"_

Comment: no dear! i mean how to write html code using javascript.

Comment: as we write html code using php.

Answer (score 0):

`how to write HTML document using external javacript from another webpage`

```
<html>
  This is html document
  with javascript from another server
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As this question is not very detailed and I cannot really understand what you are saying, I find it hard to give an answer. From what I can see, you are new to HTML and Javascript so I will quickly explain an answer.

**Link Javascript from another page, here is a more detailed version of what vp_arth said:**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

This takes a bunch of Javascript code from a webpage and puts it into a script, you can do this with your own code, just make another webpage, stick your javascript in it, and it will run on the webpage with this tag in. For this example, JQuery is being added to the page so that you can use the library.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

If you need any more help, just comment and also try to make your questions more specific.

Luca